# Can PowerShell be used as code behind for WPF

Tags: wpf, powershell, code-behind

We can use [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load to load XAML file in PowerShell, but is there some way to specify some PowerShell script as code behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now there is also [WPK](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellPack), in the PowerShellPack which makes creating WPF UI in PowerShell extremely straightforward and fun.

Answer (score 10):

PowerShell can be used to provide functionality in a WPF application.  Check out these great blog posts regarding using PowerShell and WPF...

HuddledMasses.Org - PowerBoots - a WPF GUI Toolkit for PowerShell

[PowerBoots - Shoes for PowerShell](http://huddledmasses.org/powerboots-shoes-for-powershell/)

[PowerBoots - Loading XAML Windows in PowerShell 1.0 or 2.0](http://huddledmasses.org/powerboots-loading-xaml-windows-in-powershell-10-or-20/)

Windows PowerShell Team Blog

http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2008/05/25/powershell-and-wpf-wtf.aspx

[WPF & PowerShell – Part 1 ( Hello World & Welcome to the Week of WPF )](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2008/05/22/wpf-powershell-part-1-hello-world-welcome-to-the-week-of-wpf.aspx)

[WPF & PowerShell – Part 2 (Exploring WPF (and the rest of .NET) with Scripts)](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2008/05/23/wpf-powershell-part-2-exploring-wpf-and-the-rest-of-net-with-scripts.aspx)

[WPF & PowerShell -- Part 3 (Handling Events)](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2008/05/24/wpf-powershell-part-3-handling-events.aspx)

[WPF & PowerShell -- Part 4 (XAML & Show-Control)](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2008/05/25/wpf-powershell-part-4-xaml-show-control.aspx)

[WPF & PowerShell - Part 5 ( Using WPF & PowerShell Modules)](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2008/05/26/wpf-powershell-part-5-using-wpf-powershell-modules.aspx)

[WPF & PowerShell - Part 6 (Running Functions in the Background)](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2008/05/27/wpf-powershell-part-6-running-functions-in-the-background.aspx)

[WPF & PowerShell - Part 7 (Sharing Hosts)](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2008/05/28/wpf-powershell-part-7-sharing-hosts.aspx)

Comment: No problem.  Joel "Jaykul" Bennet and James Brundage have both done a lot of work with WPF and PowerShell.  Great stuff.

Comment: The next release (you can check it out in source control on codeplex) of PowerBoots includes a .Net4 extension to allow powershell-script embedding in event handlers in xaml

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know for sure, I would guess not. Given that Visual Studio only exposes C# and VB as languages to use to build WPF applications, that implies that work needs to be done at the tool level in order to add support for WPF to a language. Since a .NET language doesn't get WPF support "for free", it's doubtful that PowerShell has the ability to be the code behind for a WPF UI.

Comment: This is inaccurate.  .NET languages largely do get WPF support "for free" (they are almost all able to access the types).  Some .NET languages have threading issues that make working with WPF troublesome, and just having access to the .NET types does not guarantee that the types will be useful to people in the language without extra work.  In PowerShell's case, you can easily access WPF for free, but you cannot use WPF in a cmdlet-like way without WPK.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The current place to look at is http://showui.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets.

Sorry Show-UI has no release yet. It is the successor to PowerBoots and WPK.